# Optimising a big Wordpress site

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, optimization

I'm looking at optimising a rather large site I've been adding to and adding to. The database has become pretty big (maybe 100,000 posts) and it has started slowing down somewhat and giving me "Mysql has gone away"errors. I've been reading about database optimisation and have ready some people saying you should only be looking to use 1-15 queries on a page.

Do people think the suggestion that only a handful of queries should be used on any page?

Am I correct in thinking that every time I use a Wordpress function such as get_permalink() I am creating a new query and new connection the database?

I have some loops in there that literally loop through 100+ users at a time and use functions such as get_user_meta() in these loops - so would this mean I am literally making 100 database queries or are they somehow cached in Wordpress?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

With issues like this, the thing to do is take the caching out of the hands of Wordpress, and make the server to the work.

Software like Wordpress and Drupal do have their own caching systems, and you should enable them, but even with them in use, there's still a certain amount of overhead for the software to load and serve the page.

So I suggest you investigate a server caching engine such as [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).

This will dramatically reduce the server load for most sites like yours; if you have a lot of requests for the same page over and over, Varnish will take over the caching and Wordpess will never even have to know that the page is being requested. No more loading PHP and the Wordpress core for every request, no more database session with every request.

If your back-end CMS software is starting to go slowly, this is the single most effective way of speeding it up.

Comment: Varnish looks interesting, will check it out.